# An idiom on idioms

Tags: idioms

Is there an idiom which conveys that there is an idiom for everything? (or for anything, or for every conceivable topic)

Comment: Welcome to English! I am not sure precisely what you are asking. Do you mean something like, "There is nothing new under the Sun"?   -  http://www.bible.ca/ef/expository-ecclesiastes-1-4-11.htm